# Microsoft Sync Framework and Integer as Identifier

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I've got to implement data synchronization between a local storage that resides on a mobile device and the server DB.

The thing is that our DB (which is already in production for many years) all uses an integer as the Id of a record. I'm afraid that changing it to be a GUID is currently not an alternative because it has too many repercussion.

Does someone has a good workaround this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following article '[Creating Primary Keys Across Databases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/15/10038656.aspx)' for some ideas.